# What rvalues have names?

Tags: c++, c++11, named, rvalue

[@FredOverflow mentioned in the C++ chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/782668#782668) that `this` is a rare case of rvalues that have names. The C++0x FDIS mentions under `5.1.1 [expr.prim.general] p4`:

> Otherwise, if a member-declarator declares a non-static data member (9.2) of a class X, **the expression `this` is a prvalue of type “pointer to X”** within the optional brace-or-equal-initializer. It shall not appear elsewhere in the member-declarator. *(emphasis mine)*

What others are there, if any?

Comment: Technically, `this`, `true`, and `false` are not names.  They're tokens which form valid rvalue expressions and which happen to look like identifiers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One prominent case are enumerators

```
enum arity { one, two };
```

The expressions `one` and `two` are rvalues (more specifically, prvalues in C++0x). Another are template non-type parameters

```
template<int *P> struct A { };
```

The expression `P` is an rvalue too (more specifically again, a prvalue in C++0x).

Comment: Standard quotes to back this up? (I know you have one, don't hide it from me! `:)`)

Comment: @Xeo It's at 5.1.1p8 and 14.1p6

Answer (score 8):

1. The boolean literals `true` and `false` are prvalues of type bool.
2. `nullptr` is a prvalue of type `nullptr_t`.
3. When you return a named variable from a function, it becomes an `xvalue` in the context of that expression, and an `xvalue` is an `rvalue` (per §3.10/1).

There may be more, but those are all I can think of at the moment (and the third is questionable -- it's really the expression that's the xvalue, but with something like `return x;` (where `x` is a local variable and you're returning the value, not a reference), the name of the variable *is* the expression. The name really refers to a glvalue, and in the expression that value (but not really the name) gets converted to an xvalue (which is an rvalue).

Comment: The third point only applies to local variables returned by value. And even then the expression is still an lvalue, but there is a special language rule that treats the object *as if* it were designated by an rvalue.

Comment: @FredOverflow: yes -- I edited in the mention of it having to be local for any of this to apply (and as I said, I agree that the third is  questionable anyway).