# Function parameter not an lvalue?

Tags: c++, lvalue

I'm creating a function to get a `const int` time in seconds and print real time in hours minutes and seconds.
`localtime` can do that, returning `tm` structure from `time.h`. What I panned to do was this:

```
bool elapsed(const int timeout) {
    //Cast the integer to time_t
    struct tm * now = localtime( (time_t&) &timeout);

    std::wcout<<L"Time elapsed: "<<now->tm_hour<<':'<<now->tm_min<<':'<<now->tm_sec<<"\r\n";
    return timeout>600;
}
```

But this throws an error: `(time_t&)`**`&`**`timeout` - expression must be an *lvalue*

Besides troubling me with `an` before a consonant, the error makes no sense to me. I've read that [lvalues are *things with names*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6397922/607407). Is this case an exception?

Comment: You're casting an `int*` to a reference to `time_t`. Either way it's wrong;, you just traded a compile error for a runtime problem (bad idea).  Also, your function receives a copy of that `int`, so the only reason to take it as `const` would be to be extremely anal about not modifying the value of *the local copy* within the function.

Comment: The use of "an" here is appropriate because lvalue starts with the sound of a vowel. For example, an X-ray.

Comment: "A unicorn." Everyone, I'd like you to meet English.

Comment: "An acrobat". "When u makes the same sound as the y in you, or o makes the same sound as w in won, then a is used." English is an inconsistent bastard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `localtime` function requires an argument of type `time_t*`, a pointer to a `time_t` object.

In your current code, you don't have a `time_t` object, so you can't create a valid pointer to such an object.

Define a local `time_t` object, initialized to the (converted) value of `timeout`, and pass that object's address to `localtime`:

```
bool elapsed(const int timeout) {
    time_t t_timeout = timeout;
    struct tm * now = localtime(&t_timeout);
    // ...
```

But if possible, it would be cleaner to declare your `timeout` parameter as a `time_t` in the first place:

```
bool elapsed(time_t timeout) {
    struct tm * now = localtime(&timeout);
    // ...
```

This all assumes that your `timeout` value is a sensible value to pass to `localtime()`. It very likely isn't. A `time_t` value represents a time, not a duration; on many systems, it's the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT.  A `timeout` value of 3600, for example, would represent 1:00 AM on Jan 1, 1970.  `localtime` as the name implies, treats it as a local time, so depending on your time zone it might be, for example, 4pm on December 31. And that's all assuming the most common interpretation of `time_t` values; the language standard only guarantees that it's an arithmetic type able to represent times *somehow*.

If your goal is to break down your `timeout` value into hours, minutes, and seconds, just do the arithmetic yourself:

```
int seconds = timeout % 60;
int minutes = timeout / 60; // integer division truncates
int hours = minutes / 60;
minutes %= 60;
```

As for why you got that particular error message: a *reference* has to refer to an *object*. When I compile your code with g++ I get:

```
c.cpp:6:45: error: invalid cast of an rvalue expression of type
            'const int*' to type 'time_t& {aka long int&}'
```

An *lvalue* is, roughly, an expression that refers to an object. Given

```
int x = 42;
```

the expression `x` is an value, but `42` and `x+1` are not.

The expression `timeout` is an lvalue, because it's the name of an object. The expression `&timeout` is *not* an lvalue. It evaluates to a value (the address of `timeout`, of type `time_t*`), but does not refer to an object, because you don't have an an object of type `time_t*` for it to refer to.

You can convert (cast) an lvalue to a reference type. Since `&timeout` is not an lvalue, the cast is invalid.

But that doesn't really matter, because converting to a reference doesn't make sense in this context. Telling you how to do the cast correctly would not be helpful, since no cast is required or appropriate for what you're trying to accomplish.  All you need is a little simple arithmetic -- no pointers, no references, no casts.

Answer (score 1):

Lvalues are indeed "things with names" (typically, even though this is not an exact rule). But in your case the "thing" in question is `&timeout`. This expression evaluates to the address of `timeout` variable. This address does not have a name. The address is just a temporary intermediate value. It is obviously not an lvalue.

The reason the compiler requests an lvalue is your cast to reference type `(time_t &)`. Only lvalues can be used as operands of such cast. This must be a typo on your part, since `localtime` expects a *pointer* to `time_t` as an argument, not a reference. Your cast was apparently supposed to look as `(time_t *)` (or, better, `(const time_t *)`), but you mistyped `&` in place of a `*`.

Of course, the very practice of *reinterpreting* an `int` lvalue as an `time_t` lvalue (which is what you do with your `&`-and-cast combination) is rather questionable. If you know that your `time_t` is an integer type and want to rely on that, then *conversion* would make more sense than reinterpretation

```
time_t tt_timeout = timeout;
struct tm * now = localtime(&tt_timeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `(time_t&)` with `(time_t*)`.

That will solve the build error. Most likely leading to a runtime error.

Comment: Ah, damnit. That's what happens when you stick to easy languages for too long.

Comment: Was just about to comment when you posted the edit.  Yes, that is certainly wrong.

Comment: I believe casting it to a reference semantically means that the value won't live beyond the scope of the expression that created it, making it an rvalue

Comment: @CDahn, as AndreyT pointed out, the problem is that the operand for the cast itself is not an lvalue as it shuold be.

Comment: -1. As you say, this will solve the build error but may cause undefined behavior, or at least give incorrect results.

Comment: It gives correct results to me. May I know what error are we talking about?

Comment: @TomasZato The kind of error you may get when `sizeof time_t != sizeof int` and depending on the endieness of your system you get either lucky, or rubbish results