# Why overloading of += never return nothing in other people's code?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Let's say I have a very simple class

```
class C { 
    private:
        int _a; 
        int _b; 
    public:
        C (int a, int b) :_a { a }, _b { b } {}
        int a () { return _a; }
        int b () { return _b; }
        bool operator== (C c) {
            return this->_a == c.a() && this->_b == c.b();
        }
};
```

and I want to overload the operator `+=` such that

```
C foo(8, 42);
C bar(1, 1); 
C zoo(9, 43);
foo += bar;
assert(foo == zoo);
```

runs fine.

As far as I've read other people code, I should write something like

```
C operator+= (C c) {
    return { this->_a += c.a(), this->_b += c.b() };
}
```

but to my understanding, `return`ing something is useless. Indeed, the assertion above does not fail even when I overload `+=` as

```
void operator+= (C c) {
    this->_a += c.a();
    this->_b += c.b();
}
```

or

```
C operator+= (C c) {
    this->_a += c.a();
    this->_b += c.b();
    return C(0,0);
}
```

TL;DR: *why shouldn't I return void when overloading `+=`*?

Comment: `+=` should return `C&` not `C`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning the left-hand side of the expression allows you to chain operators, or to use the result of the assignment in a single line, i.e.

```
int c = a += b;//this is so ugly :'(
```

or

```
if(a+=b)
{
}
```

Also, this is the behaviour that you will have on the built-in types (paragraph 13.6 of the c++ standard), so it is a good idea to mimic it for all your custom clases

Answer (score 5):

Expected behaviour of `+=` is that it evaluates as its own first operand (the `x` in `x += y`), as a value that can subsequently be assigned to. This is how `+=` works for the built-in types, and generally speaking, custom operators should behave like the built-in operators unless you have a specific reason not to (such as `operator<<` and `operator>>` for I/O).

This means the implementation should look like:

```
C &operator+= (C c) {
    this->_a += c.a();
    this->_b += c.b();
    return *this;
}
```

and it means the user can write code such as

```
if ((foo += bar) == zoo) { ... }
```

or

```
(foo += bar) += baz;
```

which are possible with the built-in types, and are sometimes (although admittedly not often) actually useful.

Your assertion says something about the side effect of `operator+=`, not its result, that's why you don't notice any possible difference based on the return type.

Comment: would you mind to better explain the first sentence?

Comment: @giuscri, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397745/what-is-an-lvalue regarding the lvalues. LHS is simply "left-hand side", i.e. the LHS of `x += y` expression is `x`.

Comment: @giuscri Re-worded to hopefully make it clearer. Thanks SingerOfTheFall for clarifying too.