# Is it possible for the template parameter to be a reference type?

Tags: c++, templates, reference, decltype, template-argument-deduction

I have started to learn C++ and currently I am trying to get started with templates, so please bear with me, if my wording is not 100% accurate.

I am using the following literature:

- C++ Templates: The Complete Guide (2nd Edition)
- Effective Modern C++: 42 Specific Ways to Improve Your Use of C++11 and C++14

The first book takes a look at the following template function

```cpp
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto max(T1 a, T2 b) -> decltype(b<a?a:b) {
  return b < a ? a : b;
}
```

and states that this definition has a drawback, since `T1` or `T2` might be a reference, so that the return type could be a reference type.

However, the second book states, that, if the `ParamType`, in our case `T1` and `T2` is neither a pointer nor a reference, which is true for our case, the reference part of the calling expression is ignored.

Illustrated with the example

```cpp
template<typename T>
void f(T param);

int x = 27; // as before
const int cx = x; // as before
const int& rx = x; // as before
f(x); // T's and param's types are both int
f(cx); // T's and param's types are again both int
f(rx); // T's and param's types are still both int
```

Now I am wondering, how could it even be possible, that the return type of the first code snippet is a reference type?

Comment: `max<const int&, const int&>(42, 51)`.

Comment: @polygamma It wont be deduced as so but someone could specify it like Jarod did in their comment.

Comment: An expression never has reference type in C or C++ (yes there are no references in C but the type system is the working the same way)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are both right :

See the code generated in [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPG9wdGlvbmFsPgojaW5jbHVkZSA8dXRpbGl0eT4gCgp0ZW1wbGF0ZTx0eXBlbmFtZSBUMSwgdHlwZW5hbWUgVDI%20CmF1dG8gbWF4KFQxIGEsIFQyIGIpIC0%20IGRlY2x0eXBlKGI8YT9hOmIpIHsKICByZXR1cm4gYiA8IGEgPyBhIDogYjsKfQoKdGVtcGxhdGU8dHlwZW5hbWUgVDEsIHR5cGVuYW1lIFQyPgphdXRvIG1heDIoVDEgYSwgVDIgYil7CiAgcmV0dXJuIGIgPCBhID8gYSA6IGI7Cn0KCmludCBtYWluICgpCnsKICAgIGludCBpe307CiAgCWludCBqe307CiAgCiAgCW1heChqLGkpOwogIAltYXgyKGosaSk7Cgp9&insightsOptions=cpp2a&std=cpp2a&rev=1.0)

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto max(T1 a, T2 b) -> decltype(b<a?a:b) {
  return b < a ? a : b;
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto max2(T1 a, T2 b){
  return b < a ? a : b;
}

max(j,i);
max2(j,i);
```

Will 'generate' :

```
template<>
int & max<int, int>(int a, int b)
{
  return b < a ? a : b;
}

template<>
int max2<int, int>(int a, int b)
{
  return b < a ? a : b;
}
```

The trouble is about C++11 `-> decltype(b<a?a:b)` if you remove it (in C++14 and more) the function will not return a reference anymore. To be more precise, since C++14, the function return type is generally deduced by using `decltype(auto)` (not just `auto`) as follows:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
decltype(auto) max(T1 a, T2 b) {
  return b < a ? a : b;
}
```

However, in this case we should use just `auto` as return type to make sure that we use type deduction based on rules for auto and not decltype in order to get what we want.

Now,

```
static_assert( is_same_v<decltype(i),int> );
static_assert( is_same_v<decltype((i)),int&> );
static_assert( is_same_v<decltype(i+j),int> );
static_assert( is_same_v<decltype(true?i:j),int&> );
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator

> 4. If E2 and E3 are glvalues of the same type and the same value category, then the result has the same type and value category [...]

> 5. Otherwise, the result is a prvalue [...]

In C++ that mean :

```
static_assert( is_same_v<decltype(true?i:j),int&> ); // E2 and E3 are glvalues 
static_assert( is_same_v<decltype(true?i:1),int> ); // Otherwise, the result is a prvalue
```

Comment: The result of ?: isn't xvalue always. The category depends on the types and value categories of the operands. I think `a ? a : b` is an lvalue.

Comment: @eerorika 'the ternary conditional expression for **some** b and c'. You right, i had misread

Comment: @PasserBy Hello, should I erase "the return..." even if erase it will make comments without purpose ?

Comment: @Martinm Yes, comments are to improve a post. Once done, the comment can be deleted by their owner. And people are encouraged to do so. (I'll delete this comment in 10 minutes)

Comment: @MartinMorterol for decltype case, what is the issue if function returns reference? Can you explain, from book not able to understand why is that a big problem.

Comment: @Daemon If you run the link on cppinsights you will get this warning `warning: reference to stack memory associated with parameter 'a' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]` which is pretty explicite ;).
If needed you may look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Answer (score 3):

> since T1 or T2 might be a reference, so that the return type could be a reference type.

I assume that this is incorrectly quoted. The return type may be a reference type, but for different reasons.

If you go a little further in your [second book](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-modern-c/9781491908419/ch01.html). In *Item 3* you will find the answer to your question.

> Applying decltype to a name yields the declared type for that name. Names are typically [lvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397745/what-is-an-lvalue?noredirect=1&lq=1) expressions, but that doesn’t affect decltype’s behavior. **For lvalue expressions more complicated than names, however, decltype generally ensures that the type reported is an lvalue reference. That is, if an lvalue expression other than a name has type T, decltype reports that type as T&**.
>
> There is an implication of this behavior that is worth being aware of, however. In
>
> `int x = 0;`
>
> x is the name of a variable, so decltype(x) is int. But wrapping the name x in parentheses—“(x)”—yields an expression more complicated than a name. Being a name, x is an lvalue, and C++ defines the expression (x) to be an lvalue, too. decltype((x)) is therefore int&. Putting parentheses around a name can change the type that decltype reports for it!

Now the only question left is:

**Is `b<a?a:b` an lvalue?**

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other)

> 4) If E2 and E3 are glvalues of the same type and the same value
>   category, then the result has the same type and value category, and is
>   a bit-field if at least one of E2 and E3 is a bit-field.

So `a` and `b` are lvalues and if they are of the same type `b<a?a:b` will also be an lvalue. See a good explanation [here](https://kukuruku.co/post/secrets-of-the-conditional-ternary-operator/).

This means that  the return type for `max(1, 2)` call will be an `int&` and for`max(1, 2.0)` will be `int`

Comment: IMO the fact `decltype` does two different things (that are only subtly different and not always different) is an abomination in language design. OTOH `static` used to be considered a terrible design choice, but it actually does two very different things (top level vs. function block) and then two closely related things (class static variable vs. function static variable)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I just want to address one thing. You wrote: "I assume that this is incorrectly quoted", the exact quote from the book is: "It might happen that the return type is a reference type, because under some conditions T might be a reference"

Comment: Martin Morterol's answer should be read along with this one. The description about the behavior of decltype is important. Only then it is clear why decltype(true?i:j) is int& and decltype(true?i:1) is int.