# Use std::move when receiving function output

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I have seen lots of discussions about using `std::move` on a function return value (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856344/when-should-stdmove-be-used-on-a-function-return-value)), and I know it's unnecessary for these cases. But what if I want to use the `std::move` semantic when receiving a function output like the codes below:

```
std::vector<double> funcA()
{
    std::vector<double> out(10000, 0.0);
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    auto out = std::move(funcA());
    return 0;
}
```

Is this a good use case for `std::move`? My understanding is `move` here can avoid a copy of the returned vector, especially when the vector size is very large. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks so much!

Comment: No, this isn't a good case. It's a pessimisation. Just return it by value and receive it by value and the copy will most likely be elided (unless you are using a very old C++ version / compiler). Here's an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/xfTMbTsab). Only one object created. No copies or moves.

Comment: Your code may result in a worse performance than without move. That's because the compiler will perform [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) when move is not there.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a good use case for `std::move`?

No.

In good use cases, `std::move` is called on an **[lvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397745/what-is-an-lvalue)**.  This gives the compiler freedom to treat the value as a temporary* ***in most cases (but not all)***.

You are calling `std::move` on a temporary*.  Telling the compiler to treat your temporary as a temporary ***in most cases (but not all)*** doesn't give new capabilities to the compiler, it takes them away.

**By "temporary", I mean [prvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues).*